# How to get the value from a property of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I'm working with [UnrealEnginePython](https://github.com/20tab/UnrealEnginePython), so the code is in python, but the API is Unreal's. I have a widget class with a UEditableTextBox variable that I'm accessing as a property of a widget class. How do I get the value from the property?

```
import unreal_engine as ue
ue.all_classes()[5494].properties()[1]

#ue.all_classes()[5494]         this accesses the widget class
#.properties()[1]               this accesses the UEditableTextBox
```

Comment: did you use `.get_property('name')` or `get_owner().get_property('name')`?

Comment: @FerhatMousavi I wasn't thinking, because the code I posted is accessing the class not the object. I have a user widget being created in the level blueprint with a variable stored in it's own blueprint. I need to access the variable after it's been created in the level blueprint from my python script. Would you know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

From what you wrote in one of the comments, you are creating a Widget in Blueprint and would like to access a property inside that widget instance.

Just a comment about how you're getting the class: you're getting the class array and using the array number to choose from. This will make your code frail, as when the position of your class changes in that array; your code won't work anymore. Instead, you can get your class like this:

```
from unreal_engine.classes import Image, YourNeatClass
```

However, you will then have a class object, and you will need to create an instance of that class if you want to check any attributes in there. And, as you said in the comment, you are making that instance through Blueprint.

Having said that, what version of unreal are you running? This code looks like old 4.22 python code.

I recommend that you set up your IDE to use the unreal stub files for the convenience of having to autocomplete: https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.1/en-US/setting-up-autocomplete-for-unreal-editor-python-scripting/

Now the very first thing you can do is set up your Python script so you can receive arguments from a Blueprint node. Here's a video on how to do that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BAM5crm-BMM

Once you receive your newly created Widget in your python code, you can even cast it to your Widget class to see all attributes directly in your Python IDE.

Ideally, you should use your widget class, but here's how you can do something with the base Widget class:

```
widget: unreal.Widget = unreal.Widget.cast(your_input_variable)
widget.get_editor_property("YourPropertyName")
```